# jest mockImplementation does not let me return a value if I have a code inside it

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

Following is the code I have:

```
subscribe: jest.fn().mockImplementation(({ next = jest.fn(() => {}) }) => {
      next('234');
      return { unsubscribe: jest.fn() };
    }),
```

When subscribe is called, it runs the function

> next

But the return gives undefined instead of

> { unsubscribe: jest.fn() }

. Any way to resolve this?

Comment: What return? And what should it return?

Comment: @Erazihel as the return statement above it should return { unsubscribe: jest.fn() } but I get undefined

Comment: It seems like you're trying to mock an observable, why not create a _real one_ with `of` or `from`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe any link for reference? I am relatively new to jest

Comment: See e.g. https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/of